# who to use scss in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js

### edit

the error : `__app` in place of `_app`.

---

I'm little bit confused about my problem. I want to use scss in my react/next app but nothing work.

I installed :

```
yarn add node-sass @zeit/next-sass
```

In my `__app.tsx` i put :

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/importer';

/**
 * includes all pages, here allows to import the css import everywhere
 * @Param {any} Component
 * @Param {any} pageProps
 * @Constructor
 */
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: any): JSX.Element {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
};
```

For the test i created the index page with :

```
import React from 'react';

function HomePage() {
  return (
    <section id='home-page'>
      <h1 className='title'>Welcome</h1>
    </section>
  )
}

export default HomePage;
```

and the scss file :

```
// importer.scss
@charset "utf-8";
@import "theme";
```

```
// theme.scss
#home-page {
  background-color: #ff0000;

  .title {
    color: #00ffff;
  }
}
```

I have too a `next.config.js` :

```js
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
module.exports = withSass({})
```

Comment: Could you recreate you project in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/hello-world)?

Comment: the script does not launch for some reason... https://codesandbox.io/embed/pedantic-knuth-d2vfu

Comment: @Titulum the github repo https://github.com/bouteillerAlan/aiweb

Comment: I created a pull request with the fixes: https://github.com/bouteillerAlan/aiweb/pull/1

Answer (score 1):

Look at their doc's https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

You are creating a custom App.js that should start with only one _ but your App.js has two.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it looks like there were some mistakes in your project setup:

1. Your `__app.tsx` file should be `_app.tsx`.
2. You should import the `importer.scss` file *with* the file extension.

[image]